# Where can i find Contacts Module in Odoo 11

Tags: module, contacts, odoo, odoo-11

Im trying to do a module like Contacts, but not exactly... what i want is localize the Contacts module in the Odoo 11 path and see how they do some of the thinks the show up in the module. So please can anybody tell where can i find the module in the Odoo 11 path.

Comment: There is already module name **Contacts Directory** Installing this module you can get your contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Contacts Directory module in your Odoo addons directory in subdirectory named contacts. The exact path in your file system depends on where you have installed Odoo. You can also explore the source in Odoo github repository at path odoo/addons/contacts, https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/11.0/addons/contacts.

There is no much content in this module. It is mainly just view definition that exposes base module views and forms.

I hope you can find what you are looking for from the hints from this module.